# An example of a group such that $G \cong G \times G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I was trying to find an example such that $G \cong G \times G$, but I am not getting anywhere. Obviously no finite group satisfies it. What is such group?

Comment: There is one finite group satisfying this...

Comment: It is more challenging to ask for a (nontrivial) finitely generated group with this property.

Comment: @PavelČoupek you mean identity..?

Comment: @DerekHolt yes derek, it looks a nice problem. Thanks

Comment: I should have mentioned, I apologize, but I was interested in non identity or infinite groups only. But editing now will be wrong, so I ll keep it as it is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take $$G = H \times H \times H \times \cdots$$ for $H$ any nontrivial group.

Comment: I don't understand.. If H is finite for example it's not true

Comment: Also if $H$ is the trivial group it's still true.

Comment: @Belgi It's the infinite product.

Comment: Oh. It's displayed wrong in the mobile site

Comment: This also should work for any $n \in N$, when $G \cong \underbrace{G\times G \times \cdots \times G}_{n\text{ times}}$, right?

Comment: @quapka no. definitely not if G is finite and nontrivial

Comment: @user3491648 So, you are saying, that in the case e.g. $H=Z/3Z$ and $H\times H \times \cdots \times H \times \cdots = G \not\cong G \times G \times \cdots \times G$?

Comment: @quapka: If $G$ is *any* group satisfying $G\cong G\times G,$ then you can readily show by induction that for all positive integers $n,$ we have $$G \cong \underbrace{G\times G \times \cdots \times G}_{n\text{ times}}.$$ Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes, thanks, did not realize that.

Answer (score 7):

Let $G$ be the trivial group, for the only finite example.

Answer (score 5):

Let $G = \mathbb Z ^ \mathbb N$ (with pointwise addition as the product). Then let $f:G \times G \longrightarrow G$ be $$f(g,h)(n) = \begin{cases} g(k), &n = 2k \\ h(k), &n = 2k+1 \end{cases}$$
You can verify $f$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is an open problem whether or not there exists a finitely presented group $G$ satisfying $G \simeq G \times G$. However, several such finitely generated groups are known. Probably the first example was given by Jones in [Direct products and the Hopf property](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJAZ%2FJAZ17_02%2FS144678870001675Xa.pdf&code=7ef937f1b5042fe29ea5704c1f57a0b3).

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the trivial group satisfies this property for reasons that are mostly unrelated to group theory. If a category has binary products and a terminal object $1$ then $A \times 1 \cong A$ in a canonical way. Of course, we also have $A \times B \cong B \times A$ canonically, so in fact a terminal object serves as a unit for the product. Thus, $1 \times 1 \cong 1$.

In the case of the category of groups we have products and a terminal object (the trivial group) so this holds.